# how to insert database column names in CSV file in shell script

Tags: bash, oracle, shell, sqlplus

I am executing below script against oracle database.

```
sqlplus -s $DBUSER/$DBPASS@$DBHOST:$DBPORT/$DBSID << FIN_SQL > $pi_cancellation.csv
SET HEADING ON
SET FEEDBACK OFF
SET LINESIZE 32767
SET PAGESIZE 0
SET SERVEROUTPUT OFF
SELECT  ROOT_PROC_INS_ID || ',' || PROCESS_INSTANCE || ',' || PROCESS_TEMPLATE || ',' || START_TIME || ',' || STATUS || ',' || ATTRIBUTE2 || ',' || ATTRIBUTE14
FROM BPMUSER.EC_PE_STATUS
WHERE START_TIME<(SYSDATE - 15) AND (STATUS='pi_halted' OR STATUS='pi_failed')
ORDER BY START_TIME DESC;
FIN_SQL
```

I want to insert column names into CSV file but not as given in sql query above but as shown below. For e.g. Order_Ref should be inserted in CSV file for Attribute2

```
ROOT_PROCESS_INSTANCE,PROCESS_INSTANCE,PROCESS_NAME,START_DATE,STATUS,ORDER_REF,LINE_NUMBER
pvm:0a12dd82,pvm:0a12dd84,TechnicalErrorProcess,21-JUN-19 07.01.58.560000 AM,pi_halted,38930,1
pvm:0a12dd77,pvm:0a12dd79,TechnicalErrorProcess,20-JUN-19 12.36.27.384000 PM,pi_halted,1572846,1
pvm:0a12dd6t,pvm:0a12dd6v,TechnicalErrorProcess,20-JUN-19 12.05.22.145000 PM,pi_halted,38929,1
pvm:0a12dd4h,pvm:0a12dd4l,TechnicalErrorProcess,17-JUN-19 07.11.43.522000 AM,pi_halted,9973686,1
```

Answer (score 0):

Echo the header row before running SQL*Plus, and turn its heading off.

```
echo 'ROOT_PROCESS_INSTANCE,PROCESS_INSTANCE,PROCESS_NAME,START_DATE,STATUS,ORDER_REF,LINE_NUMBER' > $pi_cancellation.csv
sqlplus -s $DBUSER/$DBPASS@$DBHOST:$DBPORT/$DBSID << FIN_SQL >> $pi_cancellation.csv
SET HEADING OFF
SET FEEDBACK OFF
SET LINESIZE 32767
SET PAGESIZE 0
SET SERVEROUTPUT OFF
SELECT  ROOT_PROC_INS_ID || ',' || PROCESS_INSTANCE || ',' || PROCESS_TEMPLATE || ',' || START_TIME || ',' || STATUS || ',' || ATTRIBUTE2 || ',' || ATTRIBUTE14
FROM BPMUSER.EC_PE_STATUS
WHERE START_TIME<(SYSDATE - 15) AND (STATUS='pi_halted' OR STATUS='pi_failed')
ORDER BY START_TIME DESC;
FIN_SQL
```